# EF 6 Code first Add View to database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Entity Framework 6 Code first Create View.
Sorry I am new to EF.

1) Is it a good idea to create View if you are using EF 6 code first to create a database.

2) Does creating view will really improve performance.

3) If yes, then how to define a view so it will create a view in the database.

4) Is there any fluent Api to mark the Entity object as the view so it will create view rather then Table.

Comment: Views are handled similar to tables with a DbSet and a model. You need a key field. You can reverse engineer them from the database if needed. https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2015/02/leverage-views-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: Would like a detailed answer for this, do know that #2 is true if data is gathered between tables, and the same data is accessed a lot. Though some views can degrade execution time if they are poorly implemented. Indexes can achieve similar things as a single view. So if you have a view between tables, make sure that the indexes in those tables are the entities that the view is accessing.